# tensorflow graph transfer between python and c++?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, swig

Now, I have a tensorflow graph in python, because of some reason, i need to do something to the tensorflow graph in C++。Now, my method is write the graph to file in python, and  read it back in c++ 。My question is, there is any more efficient method to do this? Perhaps use swig?

Comment: That probably is the simplest solution and unless it's something you're doing a lot I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: emmm, the simplest solution works ^ ^, thanks。。